# Is there a way to manipulate data in a text file i.e to change the values and plot them?

Tags: matplotlib

I recently started coding(just last month) for my project and I was given a set of data in a text file. I needed to plot this data for my project and I am using matplotlib to plot the data.
However, the data needs to be converted to the appropriate units(I need to multiply the first and second column by a defined value) and I was wondering if it was possible to change the data using a particular command? Or should it be done manually?

Also, this is the code I am using.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
plt.plot(x, y,'r--')
plt.show()
```

Edit--I am trying to multiply the data with a very large number which is 3.086e+16.Is it possible to multiply such a large number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is actually from `read_csv()`. If you split by `sep=\s+`, the first column gets stuck with the comma and becomes a string instead of numeric:

```py
>>> data[0]
0      8.447395301327886,
1      9.468845760980592,
...
27     35.51583248212462,
28     36.51685393258428,
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

In this case you want to split with `sep=','` (which is the default, so it can also be left out):

```py
data = pd.read_csv('Andromeda.txt', header=None)
x = data[0] * 3.086e+19
y = data[1] * 1000

plt.plot(x, y, 'r--')
plt.ylabel('speed of objects in m/s')
plt.xlabel('distance from the center')
plt.show()
```

[image: andromeda figure]

Comment: I did try multiplying the constants as you had suggested but it kept saying error. Also, I'm using an online compiler. Is there another way to multiply the constants?

Comment: @SammithS ah ok, the issue actually comes from `sep=\s+`. i updated the answer with details.